# clarification needed on phonegap vs sencha touch

Tags: mobile, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Phonegap

- allows access to native features, camera, address book, etc.
- has no built-in UI elements, something else is needed for that (JQM for example)
- (anything else?)

Phonegap build

- allows cross-compiling of an app, it could be sencha, phonegap, etc.

Sencha Touch 2

- has UI elements that display natively on each OS
- has its own build that allows cross-compiling
- can be supplemented with phonegap if access to native features if required?

Is all of this information correct? If not please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap (Cordova) essentially generates an app that uses a web browser internally to run a webapp.  The webapp that it runs can be made however you wish to make it, with any number of frameworks.

Sencha Touch is just one of those frameworks that can be used.  ST can also, however, be used to generate the native apps, but it will not allow as much access to native functionality as packaging your ST app into a Cordova app.

FWIW, it was made public last week that the new version of ST (2.3) will have easier integration with Cordova, allowing a Cordova build using the Sencha Cmd tool.